# How to exactly install pyvoice changer in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: xubuntu, python, internet, github

Yesterday I tried to install this app using this instructions (https://github.com/juancarlospaco/pyvoicechanger) but I don't understand why it's not working so I'm need a full explanation of this install. 
Sorry for English :p

Comment: What's not working ? please give us more details regarding that.

Comment: I can't launch this app after install.

Comment: I mean in the end I'm need to run pyvoicechanger in terminal but when I'm executing it. In terminal says pyvoicechanger not found

Comment: Can you test it for me please?

Comment: I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### Requisites
>
> - Python 3.6+
> - PyQt 5.10+
> - Sox (Linux package).
> - Working Microphone, Speakers and Sound System.
> - Working Sound Loopback Kernel Module

<sub>From https://github.com/juancarlospaco/pyvoicechanger#requisites</sub>

Make sure you have Python version 3.6 and later.

```
:~$ /usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.6.7
```

Python came preinstalled so no need to install, your 18.10 should have fulfill this requirement automatically.

Install the requisites.

```
sudo apt-get install sox python3-pyqt5 python3-pip
```

Install `pyvoicechanger` through pip then.

```
sudo pip3 install pyvoicechanger
```

Finally, you can launch voice changer by entering.

```
pyvoicechanger.py
```

[image]

Comment: xD thank you.yesterday my pc was unable to run this app.

Comment: but wait why i cant hear my voice changes?

Comment: You'd probably have to consult with the developer, also you might be interested to see the troubleshooting section https://github.com/juancarlospaco/pyvoicechanger#troubleshooting